# Elegant Way to Select one Element per Row in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Given...

- a Matrix `A` of shape `[m, n]`
- a tensor `I` of shape `[m]`

I want to get a list `J` of elements from `A` where 
`J[i] = A[i, I[i]]`.

That is, `I` holds the index of the element to select from each row in `A`.

Context: I already have the `argmax(A, 1)` and now I also want the `max`.
I know that I can just use `reduce_max`.
And after trying around for a bit I also came up with this:

```
J = tf.gather_nd(A,
    tf.transpose(tf.pack([tf.to_int64(tf.range(A.get_shape()[0])), I])))
```

Where the `to_int64` is needed because range only produces `int32` and `argmax` only produces `int64`.

None of the two strike me as particularly elegant.
One has runtime overhead (probably about factor `n`) and the other has an unknown factor cognitive overhead. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can create list `ind=[[1, I[1]], [2, I[2]], ...]` by using `tf.range`, `tf.pack` and `tf.transpose`, and then do `tf.gather_nd(J, ind)`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov isn't that exactly what I described?

Comment: but I guess that would mean this is just the way to go?

Comment: Oops, yes, that does look like your solution, I should've read it more carefully. It's verbose, but in the future I think we'll have some shortcuts to make it more like "A[tf.range(10),I]" by addressing https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206

Answer (score 6):

The `gather()` function provides a way to do it:

```
r = tf.random.uniform([4,5],0, 9, dtype=tf.int32)
i = tf.random.uniform([4], 0, 4, dtype=tf.int32)
tf.gather(r, i, axis=1, batch_dims=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather  late answer, but could doing

```
mask = tf.one_hot(I, depth=n, dtype=tf.bool, on_value=True, off_value=False)
elements = tf.boolean_mask(A, mask)
```

Accomplish what you're looking for?

edit: I should point out that this is NOT a good idea if `A` is already a very large tensor, as this ends up making a dense matrix.

Comment: The solution using the `batch_dims` argument of `tf.gather` avoids constructing a one-hot array.

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206) provided by @yaroslav-bulatov mentiones [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206#issuecomment-212347297) solution:

```
def get_elements(data, indices):
  indeces = tf.range(0, tf.shape(indices)[0])*data.shape[1] + indices
  return tf.gather(tf.reshape(data, [-1]), indeces)
```

Your solution is not currently differentiable (because gradients for `tf.gather_nd` are not currently supported).

Hopefully, `data[:, indices]` will be introduced soon.

Comment: Until Tensorflow 2.0, gather_nd has been differentiable, but data[:, indices] doesn't come yet.