# Tensorflow: Select one column index per row using a list of indices

Tags: tensorflow

I saw questions [39684415](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684415/tensorflow-getting-elements-of-every-row-for-specific-columns), [37026425](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026425/elegant-way-to-select-one-element-per-row-in-tensorflow), and [40722200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722200/tensorflow-index-per-row) which have answers and asked the same question.

However, these were asked over a year ago, and I was wondering if there was an updated answer to do this more efficiently. In addition, I wasn't sure if they were differentiable due to the use of gather_nd.

Comment: gather_nd is differentiable

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to implementation.
For example, suppose you have a tensor data [[1,2],[3,4]], you want to get the first column.
you can use **tf.transpose(data, perm=[1, 0])** and **tf.gather_nd(data, [[0]])**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = [[1, 3], [2, 4]]

a = tf.Variable(initial_value=data, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.transpose(a, perm=[1, 0])
fc = tf.gather_nd(b, [[0]])

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    column = sess.run([fc])[0]
    print(column)
```

Comment: Actually, If you want to get sequential columns, you can directly use `y=x[:,begin:end]`. But if you want to use random integer list to select columns  as long as you construct a list like [[a],[b],[c]] and use the method metioned.